# Does this system of equations have any solutions?

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

I would just like to know if this system has a solution:

$$\begin{cases}
x = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \cos(x+y) \\
y = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \sin(x+y)  
\end{cases}$$

I don't know how to do it at all. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hint. By summing the two equations we obtain
$$x+y=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \cos(x+y)+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \sin(x+y)=\sin(x+y+\pi/4)$$
Show that there is a unique value of $x+y$ which solves the above equation.

P.S. Note that the function $t\to f(t)=t-\sin(t+\pi/4)$ is continuous, strictly increasing in $\mathbb{R}$ and  $\lim_{t\to\pm\infty}f(t)=\pm\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

If it did $x^2+y^2=1/2$. On this circle, $t=x+y$ varies between
$-1$ and $1$. So can we find $t$ with $\cos t+\sin t=\sqrt2 t$?
Drawing a graph seems to indicate there's just one such $t$.